# How can I use FTP over TLS on port 990 using Indy idFTP component?

Tags: delphi, ssl, ftp, indy

I am trying to use Indy 10's `TIdFTP` component in Delphi 11 Alexandria to talk to a FileZilla server using TLS on port 990.

I can't get the `Connect()` method to not hang up when I call it, so obviously I'm doing something wrong.

Does anyone have any working Delphi code they would be willing to show of this specific scenario working?

```pascal
procedure TformMain.btnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  IdFTP1.IOHandler := iohFTPSE;
  IdFTP1.Username := 'test';
  IdFTP1.Password := 'Abc123!';
  IdFTP1.UseTLS := utUseExplicitTLS;
  IdFTP1.Port := 990;
  IdFTP1.IOHandler := iohFTPSE;  // a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
  IdFTP1.Connect;

  if IdFTP1.Connected then
  begin
    Listbox1.Items.Add('Connected to FTP server');
  end;
end;
```

The call to `Connect()` just hangs. On the FTP server itself, I see the `connected on port 990` message, followed by a bunch of 220 replies, but then nothing after, the call is blocked.

Comment: Note that you assigned the IO handler twice in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Port 990 is usually used for "implicit" TLS, not "explicit" TLS.

So, I would try this:

```
IdFTP1.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
```

Comment: Thanks, I have got it basically working now with the addition of these three lines.   IdFTP1.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
  IdFTP1.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
  iohFTPSE.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

Answer (score 1):

Setting correct `UseTLS` together with Dataport Protection and method sslvSSLv23 got it working for me. Thanks everyone.

```pascal
IdFTP1.Host := '127.0.0.1';
IdFTP1.Port := 990;
IdFTP1.Username := '**********';
IdFTP1.Password := '**********';

// Setup TLS
IdFTP1.IOHandler := iohFTPSE;  // a TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL
IdFTP1.UseTLS := utUseImplicitTLS;
IdFTP1.DataPortProtection := ftpdpsPrivate;
iohFTPSE.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;

IdFTP1.Connect;

if IdFTP1.Connected then
begin
  Listbox1.Items.Add('Connected to FTP server');
end;
```

Comment: DO NOT use `sslvSSLv23` directly, or even the `SSLOptions.Method` property, for that matter (as it is deprecated). What you are *really* doing is effectively telling the `SSLIOHandler` to set its `SSLOptions.SSLVersions` property to `[sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]` instead. But SSL 2.0 and SSL 3.0 are no longer secure and should never be used in modern systems. You should change `iohFTPSE.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;` to `iohFTPSE.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];` instead.

Comment: Ok thanks Remy I have made those changes.